# this keyword as parameter to a new Intent

Tags: android

From Android documentation:

```
public Intent (Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
Parameters
packageContext  A Context of the application package implementing this class.
cls     The component class that is to be used for the intent.
```

Correct me if I am wrong:

1. `A Context of the application package implementing this class.` means
   the package which contains the class I want to start.
2. `this` shouldn't work(but it works, why?), because `this` refers to the current Activity, not to the `application package` as it says in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> A Context of the application package implementing this class. means the package which contains the class I want to start.

Here, "application package", for most cases, is is simply referring to your app.

> this shouldn't work

Yes, it should.

> this refers to the current Activity, not to the application package as it says in the documentation.

Assuming that the current activity and the activity to be started are both in the same app, then `this` works just fine, as it is "A Context of the application package implementing this class". Where `this` does not work is if you are trying to start an activity from some other app, in which case you use the implicit `Intent` pattern, using an action string (e.g., `ACTION_VIEW`) instead of a `Context` and Java class.

Comment: So you are telling me that `this` won't refer to the current Activity, but to the App itself? Then what would refer to the current Activity?

Comment: @CuriousGuy: "So you are telling me that this won't refer to the current Activity" -- `this` is the `Activity`. The `Activity` is from your app. Any `Context` that is from your app will work fine in the particular `Intent` constructor that you are trying to use.

Comment: Hmm, it is still strange to me, because even though `Activity` inherits from `Context`, `this` should still refer to the Activity itself. Therefore it looks more logical to me to use `getApplicationContext()`.